# Unable to enable Set a maximum cost per click bid limit and set bid max using google adwords api

Tags: google-ads-api

I have created google adCampaigns, adGroups, Keywords, Ads, Locations using Google Adwords API
but I am not able to set "Set a maximum cost per click bid limit" using api
[image]

I have used this code to set but it's not getting set

```
       $operations = [];
        // Create ad group with the specified ID.
        $groupId = $adGroup->getId();

        $adGroupNew = new AdGroup();
        $adGroupNew->setId($groupId);
        $cpcBidMicroAmount = intval($_GET['cpc']) * 1000000;
        // Update the CPC bid if specified.
        if (!is_null($cpcBidMicroAmount)) {
            $bid = new CpcBid();
            $money = new Money();
            $money->setMicroAmount($cpcBidMicroAmount);
            $bid->setBid($money);
            $biddingStrategyConfiguration = new BiddingStrategyConfiguration();
            $biddingStrategyConfiguration->setBids([$bid]);
            $adGroup->setBiddingStrategyConfiguration($biddingStrategyConfiguration);
        }

        // Create ad group operation and add it to the list.
        $operation = new AdGroupOperation();
        $operation->setOperand($adGroupNew);
        $operation->setOperator(Operator::SET);
        $operations[] = $operation;

        // Update the ad group on the server.
        $adGroupService->mutate($operations);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $biddingScheme = new TargetSpendBiddingScheme();
    $bidCeiling = new Money();
    $bidCeiling->setMicroAmount($_GET['cpc'] * 1000000);
    $biddingScheme->setBidCeiling($bidCeiling);
    $spendTarget = new Money();
    $spendTarget->setMicroAmount($_GET['cpc'] * 1000000);
    $biddingScheme->setSpendTarget($spendTarget);
```

Do this at Campaign Level to set Bid Max Limit